# Python: get nodes INSIDE custom node-groups

Tags: python, node-editor, add-on, world

I'm trying to edit the Sun position addon (that's bundled with Blender). Normally the addon work by detecting Environnement Texture nodes, and then letting you pick which one to use, but I found out it doesn't detect the node if it's a custom group.
So I'm trying to change that
I (think) found the line in the script that detect the Env node normally:

```
    if context.scene.world is not None:
        if context.scene.world.node_tree is not None:
            col.prop_search(sp, "hdr_texture", context.scene.world.node_tree, "nodes", text="")
        else:
            col.label(text="Please activate Use Nodes in the World panel.",
                      icon="ERROR")
    else:
        col.label(text="Please select World in the World panel.",
                  icon="ERROR")
```

col is the UI box, and sp is the sun position info
And I think I need something like this:

```
    if context.scene.world is not None:
        if context.scene.world.node_tree is not None:
            col.prop_search(sp, "hdr_texture", context.scene.world.node_tree, "nodes", text="")


            if code-to-get-node-groups is not None:
                code-to-get-the-nodes-for-each-group


        else:
            col.label(text="Please activate Use Nodes in the World panel.",
                      icon="ERROR")
    else:
        col.label(text="Please select World in the World panel.",
                  icon="ERROR")
```

But the thing is I don't know how to access custom groups, or the nodes inside said groups
I tried looking it up, but my knowledge of python is pretty basic, so I'm a bit stuck.

Can anyone tell me if:

the logic is sound?
and if it is, how do I access those groups and their nodes?

thanks in advance!

Comment: A node group is basically a node containing another node tree. You access it by retrieving the node group node, then assuming it's a node tree : `nodes["Group"].node_tree.nodes`

Comment: @Gorgious  Yeah I tried that before but I got an error message saying the nodes["Group"] didn't exist, so I thought I needed to first declare a variable or something? But maybe I didn't write it right at all in the first place. Do I need to write just nodes["Group"].nodes["Group"].node_tree.nodes or do I need the full context.scene.world.node_tree.nodes["Group"].node_tree.nodes? (or even something else?)

Comment: Well I tried some more, but I ended giving up.
I kept getting errors that I didn't understand, and then on top of that I realised the Sun Position addon doesn't do what I thought it did. (I thought it moved the Sun from the HDRI value, but it does the opposite).
I solved my problem with multiple drivers instead. It's longer to setup than a button push but at least it works and I know what I'm doing.
Thanks anyway